# Let $a, b,c$ be positive real numbers such that $a+b+c=1,$ prove $(a + b) ^ 2 (1 + 2c)(2a + 3c)(2b + 3c) \ge54abc$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, symmetric-polynomials

> Let $a, b,c$ be positive real numbers such that $a+b+c=1,$ prove $(a + b) ^ 2 (1 + 2c)(2a + 3c)(2b + 3c) \ge54abc$

I think it's to be solved by AM-GM inequality but I am not getting to the final solution

here's what I thought we have 54 on RHS so we need 27*2. So could be a possibility that 3 am gm of 3 terms and 1 am gm of 2 term but unable to make such a case. I tried applying am gm individual on each bracket and multiplying all the resultants but that doesn't seem to work

applying am-gm on $(a+b)^2$ we get $>=4ab$, next we write $1+2c$ as $a+b+3c$ and apply am-gm we get $>= 3$ cube root $3$  $abc$  now the next bracket we write $2a+3c$ as $a+a+3c$ and apply am gm we get$>=3$ cuberoot $3a^2c$. And finally $2b+3c$ as $b+b+3c$ we get $>= 3$ cuberoot $3b^2c.$ Multiplying all of them we get the expression$>=81 *4 ab(abc)$

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): show some work.

Comment: @Tanishka Show me your attempts and I'll show my solution.

Comment: Ok so here's what I thought we have 54 on RHS so we need 27*2.  So could be a possibility that 3 am gm of 3 terms and 1 am gm of 2 term but unable to make such a case. I tried applying am gm individual on each bracket and multiplying all the resultants but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Show me how exactly did  you make it?

Comment: Ok applying am-gm on (a+b)^2 we get >=4ab, next we write 1+2c as a+b+3c and apply am-gm we get >= 3 cube root 3 abc now the next bracket we write 2a+3c as a+a+3c and apply am gm we get>=3 cuberoot 3a^2c. And finally 2b+3c as b+b+3c we get >= 3 cuberoot 3b^2c. Multiplying all of them we get the expression>=81 *4 ab(abc)

Answer (score 0):

Smoothing helps.

Indeed, we need to prove that:
$$(a+b)^2(a+b+3c)(2a+3c)(2b+3c)\geq54abc(a+b+c)^2$$ or
$$(a+b)^2(a+b+3c)(4ab+6(a+b)c+9c^2)\geq54abc(a+b+c)^2.$$
Now, let $a+b=constant$.

Thus, we need to prove a linear inequality of $ab$, which says that it's enough to prove our inequality for an extremal value of $ab$.

If $ab\rightarrow0^+$, so our inequality is obvious.

But by AM-GM $ab$  gets a maximal value for $a=b$.

Now, let $a=cx$.

Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$4x^2(2x+3)^3\geq54x^2(2x+1)^2$$ or
$$(2x-3)^2(4x+3)\geq0,$$ which ends a proof.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer